# Alphanumeric sorting of a string with variable width size

Tags: linux, file, sorting, alphanumeric

I am stuck in a small sorting step. I have a huge file with >300K entries and the file has to be sorted on a specific column containing alphanumeric identifiers as

```
Rpl12-8
Lrsam1-1
Rpl12-9
Lrsam1-2
Rpl12-10
Lrsam1-5
Rpl12-11
Lrsam1-101
Lrsam2-1
Act-1
Act-100
Act-101
Act-11
```

The problem is the variable width size, so I am unable to specify the second key identifier (sort -k 1.8n).The first sort is on first alphabet, then on number next to it and then the third number after "-". Can I specifically enable sorting after "-" using delimiter field so then I don't care about width of string.

Desired output would be :

```
Act-1
Act-11
Act-100
Act-101
Lrsam1-1
Lrsam1-2
Lrsam1-5
Lrsam1-101
Lrsam2-1
Rpl12-8
Rpl12-9
Rpl12-10
Rpl12-11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the above data in input.txt:

```
sort -t- -k1,1 -k2n input.txt
```

You can change the field delimiter to `-` with `-t`, then sort on the first field only (as a string) with `-k1,1`, and finally the 2nd field (as a number) with `-k2n`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works great. What if the file is tab separated and above shown example is 5th column. Can I specify two identifiers in same line such as the file is tab seperated but used "-" delimiter for 5th column or I might have to use in conjugation with awk etc.

Comment: My answer would only work for that column by itself, if it is a single column in a tab-separated file, then you will have to use another tool as well. For example you could replace the hyphens with a tab, then sort on both columns, then replace that tab with a hyphen again. How many columns are there in total? What data do the other columns contain?